# Do lithium cells degrade over time if not used?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, battery-lifespan

**Short question:**

Do lithium cells degrade over time if not used?

Will a lithium cell (backup battery 3.6 V/2.3 Ah, AA form factor) if left to sit for 10-15 years, once charged up still provide its "original capacity" or will it degrade over time?

**Longer question with background:**

I have a device (industrial lighting control processor) that has an onboard lithium cell, specifications as above. The cell provides power to the board to keep the firmware and configuration stored in case of a power outage. It is a known issue with this device that the cells eventually fail after 10-15 years of use.

The device I have is brand new in the box, and I don't really want to open it up to desolder the existing cell and solder in a new one.

I was hoping that due to the fact the device has never been used that the cell would still be at 100% health and would just need an inital charge. Is that the case or do cells degrade over time even if not used?

Comment: No, it almost certainly won't be at 100% health. See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352152X2201622X), for example.

Comment: @winny this is the battery - https://www.kempstoncontrols.co.uk/6ES7971-0BA00/Siemens/sku/76422

Comment: Oh, a _primary cell_. That explains the 10 years.

Comment: @winny im not sure i understand the comment could you expand a bit please

Comment: When people read “lithium battery”, most think of lithium-ion rechargeable, so called _secondary_ cells. Hence both mine and Cristobols comments/answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your battery will degrade in storage, certainly significantly in 15 years.  How much depends on conditions.  The mechanisms of lithium-ion degradation are shown [here](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-808-how-to-prolong-lithium-based-batteries).

If you want to put them into storage, the most common recommendation is to charge/discharge them to about 50%.  Too much or too little charge on a stored battery cause it to degrade faster.

It should be stored above 0°C, but below 25°C (refrigerator, not freezer).

Storage recommendations for several types of battery can be found [here](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-702-how-to-store-batteries).

Comment: I also thought OP was asking about li-ion cells, but it’s non-rechargeable primary lithium, so no point in discharging to 50 %.